# Answer verifcation: $\int\sin(ax)\cos(ax)\,dx$ where "a" is a constant

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I was currently doing a trigonometric substitution, and I noticed my answer is not on Wolfram Alpha [Answers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20cos(ax)sin(ax)).  This is the integral which I had to solve:

> $$\int\sin(ax)\cos(ax)\,dx \ \mathbf{\ \ \ \ a \ is \ constant}$$

My answer was: $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{a}\frac{\sin^2(ax)}2+C}$

Comment: The answer to an integration problem can easily be checked by differentiating it.

$$
\left(\frac{1}{a}\frac{\sin^2(ax)}2+C\right)'=
\frac{1}{2a}2\sin{(ax)}\cos{(ax)}a=\sin{(ax)}\cos{(ax)}.
$$

As you can see, your answer is the same function as the integrand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: notice that
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
What's the difference of the $2$ primitive functions?